# Finding the max(date) irrespective of other columns

Tags: teradata

I have a below like table

Table1

```
Id | Name  | Date
1     A      11.12.2018
2     B      12.12.2018
3     C      13.01.2017
4     D      15.06.2019
5     E      21.05.2019
```

Table2

```
Id | Marks
1     50
2     79
3     90
4     95
5     92
```

I want to select all the records having marks >  80 and i want to display max(date) for  all the selected records.  Expecting output should be like

```
Id | Name | Date
3    C      15.06.2019
4    D      15.06.2019
5    E      15.06.2019
```

Slightly handicapped as i'm new to sql and teradata. Appreciate your time and help

Thanks in advance.

This is the query that i tired,

```
SELECT a.Id, a.name , max(a.date)
FROM Table1 as a , Table2 as b
WHERE a.Id  = b.Id 
       AND b.Marks > 80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MAX` as an analytic function over the entire table, and also correct your join syntax:

```
SELECT
    a.Id,
    a.name,
    MAX(a.date) OVER () AS max_date
FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN Table2 b
    ON a.Id = b.Id 
WHERE
    b.Marks > 80;
```

An alternative to the above approach would be to use a subquery to find the maximum date across the entire table:

```
SELECT
    a.Id,
    a.name,
    (SELECT MAX(a.date)
     FROM Table1 a INNER JOIN Table2 b ON a.Id = b.id
     WHERE b.Marks > 80) AS max_date
FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN Table2 b
    ON a.Id = b.Id 
WHERE
    b.Marks > 80;
```

Comment: Thanks alot Tim Biegeleisen  :-) . It really helps.Is there any other way we can achieve it other than  this approach. Asking just out of curiosity

Comment: Yes, you may use a subquery to find the maximum date, q.v. my updated answer.

Comment: You must add the same WHERE-condition otherwise this might return a different date.

Comment: oh got it. So if i want to write a query like below, in that case should i need to add same condition whichever i'm using inside  inner query as well.

```select *
from t1  as a, t2 as b, t3 as c
where a.id=b.id and b.num=c.num  and
            a.id in (select distinct id from t4  as d and t3  as e
                        where d.id=e.num and d.rowval =  1  and  d.mark > 70);
```

Comment: bit  confused  with that concept explained above. I understood the above one is join and the one i'm asking for clarification is inner query. But should that apply in this case as well??

Comment: @dnoeth Can you help understand this?